# Two pages on Google+

Tags: google-plus, google-plus-pages

How can I add second page in Google Plus? I have personal Google+ account and my company page, but I want to create next page about my hobby. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2):

Go to www.plus.google.com

You will be re-directed to Google My Business

From the hamburger menu (circle with horizontal lines) at the top left side, choose **Brand Pages**

Once you're in the Brand Pages view, you will see a list of all your pages.

Click the large blue plus sign at the lower-right side of the screen to start the process of creating a new page.

Comment: Will it allow to create another page when the same email id has one page already?

Comment: Yes, it will. I have seven pages but was able to add another one.